# Get element by using whats inside that element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to access an element using selenium web driver using the inside text of a button element.

I want to catch this button element using "next" value.

```html
<button>next</button>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following `xpath` options to get the element with text `next`

**Option1**:

```
//button[text()='next']
```

**Option2**:

```
//button[contains(.,'next')]
```

**Option3**:

```
//button[contains(text(),'next')]
```